# Get relation from table related to pivot with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So, I got 2 models called `Team`, `User` where the `User` is related to multiple `Teams` and the `Team` has multiple `Users` included. This means I have a pivot table called `team_user`.

I want to grab the team members from a Users.

I have the relations setup as follow:

```
// In the User model
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\Team');
}

// In the Team model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\User');
}
```

How would I return the Users within a Team from a User?

I've tried `User::find(1)->teams()->users()` but this isn't working..

I'm trying to return an array like this:

```
 [
   'teamName' => 'Team #1',
   'users' => [
      [
         'username' => 'John Doe'
      ], [
         'username' => 'John Doe #2'
      ]
   ],
   'teamName' => 'Team #2',
   'users' => [
      [
         'username' => 'Doe John'
      ], [
         'username' => 'Doe John #2'
      ]
   ]
```

Comment: Lol I tried almost everything..... Except that @JoelHinz fml, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your pivot table is called `team_user` and not `team_users` you have to specify it in your relation:

```
// In the User model
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\Team', 'team_user');
}

// In the Team model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\User', 'team_user');
}
```

Then you can retrieve the teams by accessing `teams()->get()` of a user and add `with('users')` to eager load the `users` relationship of every team:

```
$teams = User::find(1)->teams()->with('users')->get();
```

Comment: I want the users `in` the team of the user. Solved it by doing `User::find(1)->teams()->with('users')->get()->toArray()`

Comment: My bad, I wasn't thinking straight. Answer is updated :)

Comment: How would I be able to set a where on the `users` relation, because I dont wan't to have my own `user_id` in the result.

Comment: You can do that with eager load constraints: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading (scroll down a bit)